# How to display Html page in our .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i wrote this code

```
 public partial class monograph : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string path = "file:///D:/CD IP/Html/Monographs/";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            path = path + Label1.Text + ".htm";
            Response.Redirect(path);
        }
    }
```

How to open html page from above code??

Comment: you mean load on the same page or open in a new page

Comment: Not only is the question poorly worded and vague, but any of the number of possible needs are most likely already asked and answered on SO, if not able to be found with a simple search on Google. [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/060ea8e0-cc63-44a3-b0dc-b531c29b8a0f/) probably answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using "file:///D:/CD IP/Html/Monographs/" for opening HTML page. You have to use relative path OR just give HTML file name, if your aspx and html page resides on same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative url.
Host your html in your application or website.

Something like this

```
Response.Redirect("~/Html/Monographs/"+fileName+".htm");
```

file: makes assumetions about the users pc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your html files in asp.net create folder in your project forder with any name and put your hmtl files. Eg

Say I have created palinData folder and copied 1.html in it. you can give a link by

```
lnk.HRef=Server.Mappath("~") + "/plainData/1.html"
```